# Subscript out of range error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to import FDF files(can be multiple) with VBA. When I run my code I got **Subscript out of range** error.

I know that the error suggests the worksheet it is looking for does not exist but I don't believe the code below actually defines the worksheet name which is probably the cause of the problem?

Can I have assistance in where, and what, code to insert to address this error? This is my code what I tried:

```
Sub FDFImport()

    Dim OutSH As Worksheet
    Dim Fname As Variant, f As Integer
    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename("FDF File,*.fdf", 1, "Select One Or More Files To Open", , True)

    For f = 1 To UBound(Fname)

      Open Fname(f) For Input As #1

      Do While Not EOF(1)

         Line Input #1, myvar
         arr = Split(myvar, Chr(10))
         arr2 = Split(arr(4), "/V")

         If InStr(1, myvar, "(Contact)") > 0 Then

            Set OutSH = Sheets("Contact")
            outrow = OutSH.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            For i = 1 To 8

               placer = InStr(1, arr2(i), ")")
               OutSH.Cells(outrow, i).Value = Left(arr2(i), placer - 1)

            Next i

         Else

            Set OutSH = Sheets("NoContact")
            outrow = OutSH.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            For i = 1 To 12

               placer = InStr(1, arr2(i), ")")
               OutSH.Cells(outrow, i).Value = Left(arr2(i), placer - 1)

            Next i

         End If

      Loop

      Close #1

      Sheets("Contact").Cells.Replace what:="(", replacement:=""

      Sheets("NoContact").Cells.Replace what:="(", replacement:=""

   Next f

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Hey Fred, I'm abit of a VBA noob, i didn't add any error handling codes. The error message doesnt show a line that the error occurs.

Comment: OK start from the beginning.  `For f = 1 To UBound(Fname)` could throw an error.  If one file is selected  `UBound(Fname)` will return 0.  Change this to `For f = LBound(Fname) To UBound(Fname)` and try again.  Just before that line you might want to add a check that `Fname` is not a Boolean (no filenames returned).

Comment: Hi Fred,

Ok, thanks for your help. Progress is as follows:

1. I've replaced 'For f = 1 To UBound(Fname)' with 'For f = LBound(Fname) To UBound(Fname)'

2.  Re-run the VBA code - error still persists.
3. How would i go about adding a boolean logic check in? Sorry i'm fairly new to VBA (basically beginner) and i'm trying to get this code to work to speed up a non-programming related comments/reviewing task.

Comment: You should be error checking your own code. Run through it line by line by entering the VBA code editor, clicking inside of the sub, and pressing F8. Each time you press F8, the code will run one more line. If you can't read the code, don't run the code.

Comment: Hi Grade, fair point. Apologies i haven't taken on a career path in excelling in VBA just yet. I followed your constructive instructions and believe the error occurs at this point:

      arr2 = Split(arr(4), "/V")

      If InStr(1, myvar, "(Contact)") > 0 Then

Comment: Have you tried that with `Option Explicit` declared at the top of your module?

Comment: Hi Mark, when i place Option Explicit within at the top of the code (module) i get a "Variable not defined" error message. and the code: Sub FDFImport() is highlighted.

Comment: You are getting "Variable not found" because `myvar`, `arr`, `arr2`, `outrow`, `I` and `placer` are not declared using the `Dim` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess based on what you have posted but give this a try

```
Sub FDFImport()

    Dim OutSH As Worksheet


    Dim Fname As Variant, f As Integer
    Dim myvar, arr, arr2, outrow, i, placer

    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename("FDF File,*.fdf", 1, "Select One Or More Files To Open", , True)

    If VarType(Fname) = vbBoolean Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For f = LBound(Fname) To UBound(Fname)

      Open Fname(f) For Input As #1

      Do While Not EOF(1)

         Line Input #1, myvar

         arr = Split(myvar, Chr(10))

         arr2 = Split(arr(4), "/V")

         If InStr(1, myvar, "(Contact)") > 0 Then

            Set OutSH = Sheets("Contact")
            outrow = OutSH.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            For i = 0 To 7

               placer = InStr(1, arr2(i), ")")
               OutSH.Cells(outrow, i).Value = Left(arr2(i), placer - 1)

            Next i

         Else

            Set OutSH = Sheets("NoContact")
            outrow = OutSH.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            For i = 0 To 11

               placer = InStr(1, arr2(i), ")")
               OutSH.Cells(outrow, i).Value = Left(arr2(i), placer - 1)

            Next i

         End If

      Loop

      Close #1

      Sheets("Contact").Cells.Replace what:="(", replacement:=""

      Sheets("NoContact").Cells.Replace what:="(", replacement:=""

   Next f

End Sub
```

When you `Split` the array will be 0 based.  Meaning you need loop through the array from `0 to X`.  When you are looping `arr2` you have `For i = 1 To 8` my guess is it should be `For i = 0 To 7` you are doing the same for `arr`  I have changed this is my answer.

Comment: Hi Fred, Thanks for your help so far. Much appreciated, honestly. I copy and pasted the code and the same error still persists.

I have the excel sheet in the same folder as the "FDF" file and i run the VBA code via a button (macro) i guess. Not sure if this approach is breaking anything.

Comment: Ok the next step you could take is first of all comment out (or remove) the for loops. so comment out the `For i = 0 To 7` all the way to `Next I` and try again.  If it works you now know you error is in the for loop, If it doesn't put that for loop back and try the same with the `For i = 0 To 11`.  you may find you have data coming in that does not split down to the arrays you are expecting.